# selang command: Looking for 'unix' parameter clarification

Tags: solaris, pam

We have an ***etrust enabled*** Solaris 11 host. I was looking at one of the scripts created by our Engineering team which has below command lines.

```
selang -s -c  "ng grp1 owner(etrust) ***unix*** groupid(1234)"

selang -s -c "nu user1 ***unix*** homedir(/export/home/user1) shellprog(/bin/ksh) userid(5678) pgroup(user1) gecos(New user creation for test purpose)"
```

When I looked at the available [selang environments](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/symantec-security-software/identity-security/privileged-access-manager-server-control/14-1/reference/selang-reference-guide/selang-environments.html), I see AC is the default environment.

Would like to know if creating user and group with unix argument in above selang commands is same as creating local user and group on unix system? If so, is unix argument just being used as server is etrust enabled?

Thanks and Regards

Akshay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The `ng` and `nu` commands create a group or user in the server's local eTrust database. When you specify the `unix` option to either of them, a local user or group will also be created using the options that follow. It's just a shortcut, and you could just as easily omit the `unix` options and create the local group or account outside of `selang` using native OS tools (e.g., `groupadd` or `useradd`).

The `unix` options are not stored in the eTrust database.

Comment: Thanks, James. If I understood you correctly, even with unix parameter user or group gets created in both server's local etrust DB and locally too. Just that, options followed by unix keyword doesn't get stored in etrust database. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation